# Getting computed property in games controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm creating a small multiplayer games using ember on the frontend.

I have a games list in the homepage, I want to show the amount of cards there are present in a game too.

```
App.Game = DS.Model.extend({
    serverSeedHash: DS.attr(),
    serverSeed: DS.attr(),
    table: DS.belongsTo('table'),
    bingoCards: DS.hasMany('bingoCard')
});
App.BingoCard = DS.Model.extend({
    player: DS.attr(),
    clientSeed: DS.attr(),
    game: DS.belongsTo('game'),
    player: DS.belongsTo('player')
});
App.GamesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            games: this.store.find('game'),
            bingoCards: this.store.find('bingoCard')
        });
    },
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        controller.setProperties(model);
    }
});

App.GamesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['game']
});

App.GameController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    amountOfCards: function () {
        return this.get('bingoCards.length');
    }.property('bingoCards.@each')
});
```

Whenever I go to a specific game I can access the `amountOfCards` property just fine by typing `{{amountOfCards}}` inside the game template.

However, when I try to display it on the homepage, it won't work in the each loop.

```
{{#each game in games}}
<tr>
    <td>{{game.id}}</td>
    <td>{{amountOfCards}} {{game.amountOfCards}}</td>
    <td>{{#link-to 'game' game.id}}Join{{/link-to}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Basically my question is: I have multiple games, each game has multiple bingoCards. I want compute a property per game based on the bingoCards. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm just wondering, isn't your computed property `amountOfCards` should be in your model `App.Game` ? It makes more sense to me.

Comment: Well, in this case it's just an example. I have more information I want to create with computed properties.
Like the total prize pool (all cards times the card price).

If I define the in the Model shouldn't my backend provide those values? (I'm new to Ember, so not sure)

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna have to specify an `itemController` that will wrap each individual game into a controller (usually an `ObjectController`) of your choice.

**Template**

```
{{#each game in controller}}
<tr>
    <td>{{id}}</td>
    <td>{{amountOfCards}}</td>
    <td>{{#link-to 'game' id}}Join{{/link-to}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

**Route**

```
App.GamesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Ember.RSVP.all([
            this.store.find('game'),
            this.store.find('bingoCard')
        ]);
    },

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        var games = model[0];
        controller.set('content', games);
    }
});
```

**Controllers**

```
App.GamesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'game'
});

App.GameController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    amountOfCards: function () {
        return this.get('bingoCards.length');
    }.property('bingoCards.@each', 'bingoCards.length')
});
```

You can read more about it on the [Ember API](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html)

Comment: When changing `{{#each game in games}}` to `{{#each game in controller}}`suddenly there are no results anymore.

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't see the mistakes in `App.GamesRoute`, I updated the anwser.

Comment: The controller indeed now has games. But the BingoCards are not loaded anymore. amountOfCards gets called now (I use a console.log to verify) but the length is zero..
That's what I used the `Ember.RSVP.hash` for (not sure if it was a right solution).

Comment: I updated my answer, basically in your route the return of `model` is automatically set to the `content` property of your controller. In our case the `content` property should contains an array of games.

Comment: Thanks again. I must be getting real annoying now.

I get the list of games now, but the `amountOfCards` property is still `0`. Also all the bingoCards get loaded.

Whenever I go inside a specific game `#/game/1` I do get the right amount of cards.